# pandas how to speed up the long running process

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm reading the data from a csv file into dataframe, the file has 5 columns and has about the 300k rows, now I have build another 3 dataframes which are about 1.2 million, 400k and 500k rows. I need to check for a particular values from these 2 dataframes and depending upon the result from the three I need to pick one. My is code is below. The process is running forever. I'm the reading the source data in chunks and I have even indexed the key columns even then performance is very slow.

Here is the pseudo code is below, where do you think the performance issue is.

ps: the look up dataframe size are approx 300 ~ 500 MB each.

```
def lookup1(val, date):
    # some ecode to get the lookup_data1
    return lookup_data1[(lookup_data1['key'] == val) & (date >= lookup_data1['start_dt']) & (lookup_data1['end_dt'] >= date)].required_value

def lookup2(val, date):
    # some code to get the lookup_data2
    return lookup_data2[(lookup_data2['key'] == val) & (date >= lookup_data2['start_dt']) & (lookup_data2['end_dt'] >= date)].required_value

def lookup3(val, date):
    # some code to get the lookup_data3
    return lookup_data3[(lookup_data3['key'] == val) & (date >= lookup_data3['start_dt']) & (lookup_data3['end_dt'] >= date)].pd.required_value

# driver process

source_data = pd.read_csv("some file in chunks")
date = pd.datetime('today')
for chunk in source_data:
    chunk['result1'] = chunk['val1'].map(lambda x: lookup1(x, date))
    chunk['result2'] = chunk['val2'].map(lambda x: lookup2(x, date))
    chunk['result3'] = chunk['val2'].map(lambda x: lookup3(x, date))
    chunk['final'] = chunk['result1'].fillna(chunk['result2']).fillna(chunk['result3'])
    chunk.to_csv("somefile")
```

Comment: Performance issues are often not where one *thinks* they are. That's why people invented [profilers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html). Why don't you follow that link and see if you can *reliably* find the bottleneck for yourself?

Comment: One of the first places people look for performance boosts in python is [pypy](https://pypy.org/performance.html). It's an alternate distribution of python with a more limited interface (no advanced unpacking for example), but it runs much faster, and it does [support pandas and numpy](https://morepypy.blogspot.ie/2017/10/pypy-v59-released-now-supports-pandas.html). Might be worth looking in to.

Answer (score 0):

## Vectorize

`& (date >= lookup_data3['start_dt']) & (lookup_data3['end_dt'] >= date)` always stays the same, so why not do

```
source_data = pd.read_csv("some file in chunks")
date = pd.datetime('today')

lookup1_date = lookup_data1[(date >= lookup_data1['start_dt']) & (lookup_data1['end_dt'] >= date)]
....
```

Like this the 3 lookups don't have to do that each time, and then you perhaps can even just use `.loc`

## Groupby

If there is a limited number of values in the `chunk['val1']`, a `groupby.transform` will work faster here than a `map`

Comment: I cant find a good example to use vectorization most of the ones I see are using merge operations. I tried doing chunk['result3'] = lookup3(chunk['val1].values, date) but this doesnt work. can you pls give me an example on how to do it for my use case. Thanks!